# How to show Popup Window

Tags: java, popupwindow

What I’m trying to do is a simple program that saves a file in some location specified by the user. I want to do this using an ActionListener from the save option at the File menu. I’m not sure if JPopupMenu will be useful for this. Any ideas?

Comment: I "think" you want a `JFileChooser`, see [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for more details

Comment: I'm trying that, but i don't see the save option, just the open one

Comment: `int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);`

Comment: Thanks man, that solved it!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [FileChooserDemo.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java).

The relevant part is this:

```
int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
    //This is where a real application would save the file.
    log.append("Saving: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
} else {
    log.append("Save command cancelled by user." + newline);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that's exacty what I was trying to do!

Comment: When I save the file, the saved text is all in one line, can I change this?

Comment: What text? There is not text here. You just get a File object and can write to it.

Comment: In my program i manage to capture text from a JTextArea and save it into a file, but it appears all in one line

Comment: Sorry, I am no psychic :) This seems to be way beyond the scope of this question. Maybe ask another question with the relevant code.